# Selecting fields command gives error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I want to sort multiple fields in an access data base but being a newbie I took reference from MSDN program and first trying to sort on a single field. I'm getting error From syntax wrong on the following lines.

```
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT ACT_CD, " _
& "SNO FROM Banks_Trnx_2018-2019" _
& "ORDER BY SNO DESC;")
```

The full program as follows.

```
 Option Compare Database

Sub OrderByX()

    Dim dbs As Database, rst As Recordset

    ' Modify this line to include the path to Northwind
    ' on your computer.
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("E:\FY_2018-2019\Banks\Banks_Trnx_2018-2019.accdb")

    ' Select the last name and first name values from
    ' the Employees table, and sort them in descending
    ' order.
   Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT ACT_CD, " _
        & "SNO FROM Banks_Trnx_2018-2019" _
        & "ORDER BY SNO DESC;")
    ' Populate the Recordset.
    rst.MoveLast

    ' Call EnumFields to print recordset contents.
   ' EnumFields rst, 12

    dbs.Close

End Sub
```

I am clueless. Please help. As already mentioned I would like to sort on three fields (multiple fields) comprising of text and numerical fields which presently I can easily do by setting columns in proper order and selecting them together while sorting. Since it is a repetitive operation I am trying to develop VBA procedure for the same. Any pointer in the right direction shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Adjust your SQL to include the fields to order by (if not SNO). This is very basic so, If that is new to you, look up a guide/tutorial on "Beginning with SQL" or similar.

Comment: @Gustav  I have taken the program reference from following link 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208913(v=office.12).aspx'. AS such I have tried to learn . If this is so basic why MsdN should misguide. I have not appreciated down votning on my genuine effort and question. Further i would have appreciated corrected syntax line to help me. At my age of 72 It is to keep my spirits high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your sql to a variable first - makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot - you'd be able to see you've left out some spaces between keywords and table

```
   Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT ACT_CD, " _
        & "SNO FROM [Banks_Trnx_2018-2019]" _
        & "ORDER BY SNO DESC;")
```

Should be (with added brackets for table as suggested by @skkakkar)

```
   Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT ACT_CD, " _
        & "SNO FROM [Banks_Trnx_2018-2019] " _
        & "ORDER BY SNO DESC;")
```

Comment: Problem appears at different place.There is something wrong in the code portion for opening the database. The path is not getting recognized  and as such database itself in not opening while debugging the program.. I am working on solution for the same.

Comment: If this or the other provides the answer to the question it's probably worth marking one as such. You're encouraged to start a new question for new problems.

Comment: Sort portion works but there are other issues for which I will raise a separate question. Thanks for your kind guidance in this matter.

Answer (score -1):

You have a - in your table name.  I didn't even think that was allowed, either put brackets around your table name or change the table name.

```
"SELECT ACT_CD, " _
& "SNO FROM [Banks_Trnx_2018-2019]" _
& "ORDER BY SNO DESC;"
```

or

```
"SELECT ACT_CD, " _
& "SNO FROM [Banks_Trnx_2018_2019] " _
& "ORDER BY SNO DESC;"
```

and change table name.

Comment: i have made corrections as per your advice but getting the same error. Can you advise me something based on Gustav comments. Changed code as follows Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT ACT_CD, " _
        & "SNO FROM Banks_Trnx_2018_2019" _
        & "ORDER BY SNO DESC;")

Comment: Add a space after your bracketed table name  - see my answer

Comment: Yup, totally missed the space in there, you will need that.